Trouble setting up Linux on Nintendo Switch
I'm a complete noob to Ubuntu and I've been trying to set it up on my Nintendo Switch, but I keep getting the same error that says "Failed to mount rootfs" on boot. I've tried doing the installation process from scratch multiple times with different versions of Ubuntu but no luck.
Below is a log that was in a note file on the root of the fat32 partition. It was produced during a Fedora installation,
but it looked the same for other versions. 
I think it says what's wrong, but I don't really understand it. 
What does it mean?
I also noticed that the Linux partition disappears from the partition manager after I flash Linux.  I don't know if that's normal.
[ 3.397086] [ 15:19:50.078 ] Searching for rootfs 
[ 3.398489] [15:19:50.079 ] Root device found: [ 3.709593] 
[ 15:19:50.390 ] Root device found: /dev/mmcblk0p2 [ 3.711240] 
[ 15:19:50.392 ] Found devnode: /dev/mmcblk0p2 [ 3.712772] 
[ 15:19:50.394 ] Checking dev node for errors 
[ 3.744397] tegra-xusb 70090000.xusb: entering ELPG 
[ 3.745025] tegra-xusb 70090000.xusb: entering ELPG done [ 3.793294] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p2): invalid boot record signature 
[ 3.793323] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p2): failed to read boot sector 
[ 3.793343] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p2): failed to recognize exfat type 
[ 3.794142] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x690aff3a) 
[ 3.794170] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock 
[ 3.794581] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x41f41e1f) 
[ 3.794607] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock 
[ 3.794641] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) -read(0x690aff3a) 
[ 3.794664] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock 
[ 3.794688] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x41f41e1f) [ 3.794710] F2FS-fs (mmcblk0p2): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock 
[ 3.797859] [ 15:19:50.479 ] FATAL: ERROR: /dev/mmcblk0p2 mount fail... 
[ 3.876309] [ 15:19:50.557 ] Bootdrive found

How can I resolve the problem(s)
and get Ubuntu to work on my Nintendo Switch?

You need to describe all the steps that you did.

(1) Did you copy & paste that log file, or did you manually retype it?   It looks mangled.   Please verify it and correct it, if applicable.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.)  In particular, I’m looking at (a) [ 3.7…] appearing at places other than the beginning of a line, (b) “1th” and “2th” (should be “1st” and “2nd”?), and (c) -read (should be - read?).  (2) You say, “it looked the same for other versions”.   What looked the same as what?  (3) Can you provide any more context for the “Failed to mount rootfs” error message?
